# Using AFNetworking to download a pdf from the web in appdelegate and then trying to load that stored pdf in a UIWebview on another page

Tags: pdf, uiwebview, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to download a pdf (that will change on a weekly basis) and save it into the documents directory with this code:

```
//Get the PDF    

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somewebsiteaddress/CurrentEdition1.pdf"]];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CurrentEdition1.pdf"];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", filePath);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[operation start];
```

I then want to read that saved file in another section of the app in a UIWebView (after it has downloaded) and use this code:

```
//Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder

NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CurrentEdition1.pdf"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webVieweedition setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[webVieweedition setDelegate:self];

[webVieweedition loadRequest:requestObj];
```

I have used a few single page pdf documents to test with - loading them up on the server and then seeing if they are downloaded and then viewed when changed. Problem is, this seems to only be working about 50% of the time.  I'll put a new file up and sometimes the correct one will be shown in the UIWebView and sometimes it will show the previous one and not the new one. I am waiting until I see the download completed message before I try to go to the UIWebView (although I know clients won't do that, but that's a whole other question). Anyway, I'm new to XCode and have just been a web html guy. This has had my head spinning for two days. Using Storyboards, ARC, XCode 4.6.2.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood right, sometimes you see the same pdfs in app, although you changed them on webserver?May be the reason is cache, try construct request this way, ignoring caching

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somewebsiteaddress/CurrentEdition1.pdf"]  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! I think that's the answer. I just tested it about 8 times, swapping out pdf's  on the server and every time it showed the correct one inside that app. That's NOT what was happening before. It was hit or miss!  Tried to Vote the answer up, but guess I'm too new to allow it.

Comment: I was jumping up and down too soon. I was using small 1 page pdf's to test with. When I go to a standard size document and go to the webview where it should show before the nslog reports that it has downloaded, it's a black screen. If I go off somewhere and then come back to it again after that, it's still a black screen - never shows the pdf.

Comment: but if you use old variant with cache for these big pdfs, are they disolaying correctly?

Comment: No - it's just that if you get to the UIWebView that is to display them before it is fully loaded, you get an empty view. I put a fix on that by having a refresh button in the nav bar. So, if they get there and the pdf file is still downloading in the background, they can hit the refresh view and once it's in the Documents directly, it will show properly.